# VSCode Failed to update extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm facing issue with `VSCode` for a while, I'm unable to detect the issue which prevent me to update `Extensions`

[image]

`Failed to update 'ms-python.python'.`

`Failed to update 'formulahendry.code-runner'.`

Comment: Are you able to install new extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's all about `DNS` issue:

Click that [Link](https://ms-python.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-python/python/2019.8.29288/1565127378610/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Default) and if you able to see the logo so i will consider another solution.

But if not so change your `DNS` to be:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

OR

```
1.1.1.1
1.0.0.1
```

Comment: @OmarHasan what happens when you click the link?

Comment: @OmarHasan which error msg are you receiving ! kindly upload a screen-shot for that.

Comment: cant upload image here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209290/discussion-between-omar-hasan-and--c).